# Match a number with fixed digits while scraping web content

Tags: text-processing, grep, curl, html

I'm trying to parse a source web pages, trying to find all href similar to this:

```
href='http://example.org/index.php?showtopic=509480
```

where the number after `showtopic=` is random (and with 6 fixed number of digits eg 123456 - 654321)

```
while read -r line
do
    source=$(curl -L line) #is this the right way to parse the source?
    grep "href='http://example.org/index.php?showtopic=" >> output.txt 
done <file.txt #file contains a list of web pages
```

How can I grab all the line if I don't know which is the number? Maybe a second grep with a regex? 
I was thinking to use a range in awk similar to:

```
awk "'/href='http://example.org/index.php?showtopic=/,/^\s/'" >> file.txt
```

or a double grep as:

```
grep "href='http://example.org/index.php?showtopic=" | grep -e ^[0-9]{1,6}$ >> output.txt
```

Comment: your grep command is incomplete. You need to feed it something to read from. Does `echo "$source" | grep "href='http://example.org/index.php?showtopic="` work for your problem ?

Comment: You can use regexp directly after curl `curl -L "$line" | grep or sed or awk or…` e.g. `grep -Po "href=\'?http://example.org/index.php?showtopic=\K[0-9]+"`

Comment: Can you explain this please: \K[0-9]+

Answer (score 0):

```
cat input.txt |grep "href='http://example.org/index.php?showtopic=" > output.txt
```

cat outputs the content of the file which is piped to grep. grep compares it line by line and writes whole lines into output text.

Alternatively you could use sed:

```
 sed -n "\#href='http://example.org/index.php?showtopic=#p"  input.txt >  output-sed.txt
```